# wordpress adding custom columns to custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently working with WooCommerce, a eCommerce plugin for WordPress. WooCommerce products get setup in a new post-type called product. I have the following code which adds a custom column to the edit screen for this post type:

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_columns', 'my_edit_product_columns' ) ;
function my_edit_product_columns( $columns ) {
$columns = array(
    'myfield' => __( 'My field' )
);
return $columns;
}
```

This works fine, but unfortunatley it add's it as the last column. Is there a way to order the columns? I would like this column to be directly after the "Price Column"

Answer (score 1):

$columns that is being passed to your function my_edit_product_columns is an array of all of the existing columns. You can replace the entire thing or use any standard array manipulation to change the columns & column order.

For example, if you wanted to specify the columns you would do something like (taken from an events custom post type I use):

```
$columns = array(  
                "cb" => "<input type=\"checkbox\" />",
                "title" => "Event Name",  
                "event_date" => "Date",   
                "start_time"=>"Time",
             );
```

So if you simply print_r($columns) to see what it currently has, you could manually reorder it.

To insert your column at a specific position in the existing $columns array use:

```
# Insert at offset 2
$offset = 2;
$newArray = array_slice($columns, 0, $offset, true) +
        array('new_column_id' => 'New Column Name') +
        array_slice($columns, $offset, NULL, true);
```

See this thread for more on that: [array_splice() for associative arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783089/array-splice-for-associative-arrays)

//ADDED

I just tested this out locally on a custom post type I have in use called products. This code works fine for me. The offset starts with column 1, so to make my new column be the second one, I set offset at 2.

```
   public function productsListColumns($columns){
    $columns = array(  
                "cb" => "<input type=\"checkbox\" />",
                "title" => "Product",  
                "price" => "Price"
             );  
            $offset = 2;
            $newArray = array_slice($columns, 0, $offset, true) +
            array('new_column_id' => 'New Column Name') +
            array_slice($columns, $offset, NULL, true);
    return $newArray;  
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i have tried the array_slice and the column still ends up being the last one?

Comment: very cool answer - works much nicer than trying to hack this with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following code. You just need to replace your post type with TribeEvents::POSTTYPE

```
  add_filter('manage_' . TribeEvents::POSTTYPE . '_posts_columns', 'column_headers');
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'custom_columns' , 10, 2 );

function column_headers($columns)
{
    $columns['tickets-attendees']   = __( 'Attendees', 'tribe-events-calendar');
    return $columns;
}
function custom_columns( $column_id, $post_id ) {

    if ( $column_id == 'tickets-attendees' ) {
         //echo $post_id;
         $items = TribeEventsTickets::get_event_attendees($post_id );
         $attendeeCount = count($items);
         ?>
         <a href = "edit.php?post_type=tribe_events&page=tickets-attendees&event_id=<?php echo $post_id; ?>"><?php echo $attendeeCount; ?></a>

         <?php 

    }
}
```