# add custom column to custom page in admin panel programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, themes

```
function refine_active_methods( $contactmethods ) {
    $contactmethods['Last Active'] = 'Last Active';
    return $contactmethods;
}
add_filter( 'user_contactmethods', 'refine_active_methods', 10, 1 );

function refine_modify_user_table( $column ) {
    $column['Last Active'] = 'last Active';
    return $column;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'refine_modify_user_table' );
```

how to add a custom column to a custom page in the admin panel
I find the following code to insert a column in the user menu

Comment: Does this help? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/253640/adding-custom-columns-to-custom-post-types

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wordpress adding custom columns to custom post type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021944/wordpress-adding-custom-columns-to-custom-post-type)