# PHP - Move element in array to second position

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have simple array from Wordpress `manage_posts_columns` filter, to change the columns in custom post type admin. The array looks like

```
$columns = array ('lastname' => 'Lastname', 'firstname' => 'Firstname', 'city' => 'City' );
```

and I'm adding ID column

```
$columns['id'] = 'ID';
```

I would need to move the id element to second position in the array. How can this be done?

Comment: What for? Associative array need not to be ordered.

Comment: The columns in Wordpress admin are displayed in the order of the array elements - and I need the ID column to be in second position.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783089/array-splice-for-associative-arrays

Comment: Answer in the #MLeFevre link, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you can use `array_unshift` to prepend elements onto an array, or `array_push` to add an element at the end of the array.

To reorder the associative array, you can use `array_splice`. A good example is here: http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php#92651