# PHP in-place change a single key in an associative array?

Tags: php, replace, key, associative-array, in-place

Suppose I have this associative array:

```php
$fruits = array(
 'red'   => 'strawberry',
 'blue'  => 'banana',
 'green' => 'apple',
);
```

I want to change the key `blue` into `yellow`. Note that I want to change a **key**, not a value. I could do this:

```php
$fruits['yellow'] = $fruits['blue'];
unset($fruits['blue']);
```

But this results in `'yellow' => 'banana'` being at the *end* of the array. If I'd need to maintain the order of the array, so `'yellow' => 'banana'` is at the same position as `'blue' => 'banana'` was before, how do I do that?

Of course I can reconstruct the entire array, adding all key/value pairs and just inserting the `yellow` instead of `blue` key, but that seems a rather sluggish way of doing this.

Is there a smarter / more efficient (preferably PHP native) approach to it, to do this in-place?

Comment: Actually, what you have is the right one. There's no order here. That doesn't make any difference. Why do you need a specific ordering? Then you can use numerical indices right?

Comment: You must first understand how arrays in php work....http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: @PraveenKumar Unless I'm mistaken, PHP arrays are ordered? (also according to @GeorgePant 's link?) if I do `implode(' ',$fruits)` I'm always getting the same result, i.e. `"strawberry banana apple"` in that order.

Comment: @RocketNuts you should understand how php arrays work before rejecting correct answers for not beign "smart"/"efficient".If you understand that in php the order of associative arrays is just the order by which elements are inserted into an array then you will understand that the most efficient and smart way to do this is to rebuild the array.

Comment: @GeorgePant Ehm, I didn't reject any answer yet? I only commented to cpugourou's answer, asking what his answer offers over what I already suggested in my OP. Furthermore I already mentioned that I can of course rebuild the array manually, I was merely wondering if there was some native function or operator built into PHP that could do the same thing. You can obviously change *values* in arrays in-place, and my question was simply if that's also possible for *keys*.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to get the keys using  array_keys,apply a function to change them as you want and then combine the new keys with the values using array_combine

```
 $array = array_combine(array_map('replace_key', array_keys($fruits)),  $fruits);

    function replace_key($key){
     if($key=="blue") return "yellow";
     return $key;
     }
```

Another solution would be to use `array_walk`

```
 $result = array();
     array_walk($fruits, function (&$value,$key) use (&$result) {
      if($key=="blue") $key="yellow";
      $result[ $key ] = $value;
      });
 print_r($result);
```

Another way of doing it (and probably faster) is by using a `foreach` loop and rebuild the array.And if you want a generic solution just write a simple function based on this code:

```
 $temp_array=array();

 foreach($fruits as $key=>$value){

 if($key=="blue") $key="yellow";

 $temp_array[$key]=$value;
 }

 $fruits=$temp_array;
```

Comment: @mickmackusa Did you actually try to run any of these scripts before posting a comment about them ?

Comment: Looks like I didn't test any of them. I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

You could completely rebuild a new copy of the array with the new data in the right place.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/X6s4n))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($fruits as $k => $v) {
    $result[$k === 'blue' ? 'yellow' : $k] = $v;
}
var_export($result);
```

---

You cannot use `array_splice()` because it doesn't preserve associative keys.

---

You can use two `array_slice()` calls around your new element, then the only decision is how to find the offset.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/dTvao))

```
if (key_exists('blue', $fruits)) {
    $offset = array_flip(array_keys($fruits))['blue'];
    $fruits = array_slice($fruits, 0, $offset, true)
              + ['yellow' => $fruits['blue']]
              + array_slice($fruits, $offset + 1, null, true);
}
var_export($fruits);
```

Either snippet's output:

```
array (
  'red' => 'strawberry',
  'yellow' => 'banana',
  'green' => 'apple',
)
```

Answer (score -1):

The following example is largely taken from [array_splice() for associative arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783089/array-splice-for-associative-arrays)

```
$newArray = array_slice($fruits, 0, $offset, true) +
            array('yellow' => 'banana') +
            array_slice($fruits, $offset, NULL, true);

                        print_r($newArray);
```

If we know the offset of where the key "blue" is, we can add a new key of yellow in it's place.

So in your case the offset is 1 because blue is the second key in the array.

Comment: This doesn't answer this question. Tell in your answer, how is this relevant to this question?

Comment: This answer "injects" a new associative element,  it does not replace a qualifying associative element with a new associative element.  https://3v4l.org/GBCin

Answer (score -1):

The fastest way:

```
foreach ($fruits as $key => $value){ 
     if ($key === "blue") {
         $fruits["yellow"] = $value;
         unset($fruits[$key]);
     }
 }
```

Comment: How is that faster than (or even as fast as) what I posted in my question?   (I mean `$fruits['yellow'] = $fruits['blue']; unset($fruits['blue']);`)

Comment: This snippet will just append the new associative element to the end of the array -- not what is called for in the question.